# pre-commit is failing with "Missing required key: rev"

Tags: pre-commit.com

I've been using the pre-commit tool for years! and it's worked great until recently when it started failing with a mysterious error message:

```
$ pre-commit run flake8 --all-files
An error has occurred: InvalidConfigError: 
==> File .pre-commit-config.yaml
==> At Config()
==> At key: repos
==> At Repository(repo='https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks')
=====> Missing required key: rev
Check the log at /home/asottile/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log
```

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your particular case has been warning since may of 2019:

```
$ pre-commit run flake8 --all-files
[WARNING] Unexpected key(s) present on https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks: sha
flake8...................................................................Passed
```

you can fix your case by running `pre-commit migrate-config` which will update `sha` to `rev`:

```
$ pre-commit migrate-config
Configuration has been migrated.
$ pre-commit run flake8 --all-files
flake8...................................................................Passed
```

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit